# How to access a class variable from a foreach in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to push data to  `this.organizationIDList`. I'm getting error undefined while pushing. How to push data to that variable?

```
 class NewsScreen extends React.Component {
     render() {
         this.organizationIDList = [];

         this.organizations.forEach(function (organization) {
             this.organizationIDList.push(organization.id);
         });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
            this.organizations.forEach((organization) => {
                this.organizationIDList.push(organization.id);
            });
```

Or pass `this` to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which accepts a `thisArg`

```
            this.organizations.forEach(function (organization) {
                this.organizationIDList.push(organization.id);
            }, this);
```

The above code can also be written as:

```
this.organizationIdList = this.organizations.map(organization =>organization.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function like below

```
this.organizations.forEach((organization) => {
   this.organizationIDList.push(organization.id);
});
```